# Displaying icons vertically HTML

Tags: html, css

I am using icons as navigation for an app i am creating. They are currently displayed horizontally as shown here: https://gyazo.com/bb7cbab48941ffd2e2d2b2fa5c748d72

What do I need to do to make these stack vertically? Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         .navbar {
         width: 100%;
         background-color: #555;
         }
         .navbar a {
         float: left;
         text-align: center;
         padding: 12px;
         color: black;
         text-decoration: none;
         font-size: 17px;
         }
         .navbar a:hover:not(.active) {
         background-color: grey;
         border-radius: 20px;
         }
         .active {
         background-color: yellow;
         border-radius: 20px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <div class="navbar">
         <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-align-justify"></i></a>
         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-wifi"></i></a>
         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i></a>
         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i></a>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help or advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following styling on ".navbar a" in your css

```
.navbar a {
display: block;
}
```